# Should ggplot2 dev version depend on rlang > 1.0.0 due to exported on_load() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had trouble installing the dev version of `ggplot2` from GitHub. I got the below error:

```
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in on_load({ : could not find function "on_load"
Error: unable to load R code in package 'ggplot2'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status
```

I went searching for the `on_load()` function and found that it is in `rlang`, but has only been exported since version 1.0.0 ([commit](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/pull/1291/commits/aed5c8c55290ca4abb2a15fcdcb57c7c1a7448b5); see [version 1.0.0 NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/news/news.html#r-apis) too). Upgrading my `rlang` solved the install issue for me.

Does this mean the dev version of `ggplot2` should depend on `rlang` >= 1.0.0? Maybe using `rlang:::on_load()` instead of just `on_load()` will prevent this upgrade in the dependency, as those functions did exist in `rlang` 0.4.10.

Comment: Yes it should update the rlang dependency in the description. I noticed this too when I tried to make a [PR](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4707#issuecomment-1068554368).

Comment: This seems like it would be more appropriate so ask the ggplot2 developers. You can file a github issue at https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues Otherwise it's not clear how anyone else would answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ggplot2`'s dev version should depend on `rlang` >= 1.0.0 if it wants to continue using `on_load()`/`run_on_load()`. From the comments, at least one other person has run into this problem. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4797) about this.